# Sun Solaris 8 - Couldn't set locale correctly

Tags: unix, solaris

Every time I enter into a user account or to the root account I receive the message "couldn't set locale correctly".

Entering local it displays:

```
enter code here LANG=
                LC_CTYPE="C"
                LC_NUMERIC="C"
                LC_TIME="C"
                LC_COLLATE="C"
                LC_MONETARY="C"
                LC_MESSAGES=C
                LC_ALL=
```

How I can solve this out....?

Comment: There seem to be a couple of (possible) solutions to this. Try doing Google search for your error message. Maybe someone around here has a "definitive" answer, if one exists.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at /etc/TIMEZONE , which should be linked to /etc/default/init, you should have something like:

```
TZ=US/Pacific 
LC_COLLATE=en_US
LC_CTYPE=en_US
LC_MESSAGES=C
LC_MONETARY=en_US
LC_NUMERIC=en_US
LC_TIME=en_US
```

If you don't, add those values and test it out -  reboot.